# comparing two dates in different AS columns

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have two columns with date values.I'd like to filter them to see the result only when the two columns have similar values.
I have two questions in "Where" part. Can anyone help me with this?
1)How can i compare the value between this two column with date values?
2)If i have varchar value instead of dates, how can i compare two values?

```
SELECT [USERNAME], count(*) AS [NumberOfHappening], min([date1]) AS [FirstDate], max([date2]) AS [SecondDate]
FROM TableMain

WHERE CAST([FirstDate] AS DATE) = CAST([SecondDate] AS DATE)
GROUP BY  [USERNAME]
ORDER BY 'NumberOfHappening' DESC
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by similar values? Same year, same year & month, same year & month & day?

Comment: whatever is your situation, if you want to use varchar value as date, then it is better to convert varchar value into datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the orginal date values appropriately typed or do you store date/time-values in string columns? If so, you should really change this...

If I get this correctly, you want to find records, where `date1` and `date2` are on the same day. Casting a `DATETIME` to `DATE` will get rid of the time portion.

You can use a CTE to use the column aliases directly

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT [USERNAME], count(*) AS [NumberOfHappening], min([date1]) AS [FirstDate], max([date2]) AS [SecondDate]
    FROM TableMain
    GROUP BY  [USERNAME]
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE CAST([FirstDate] AS DATE) = CAST([SecondDate] AS DATE)
ORDER BY NumberOfHappening DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
The second query works well but the first query doesn't work. It shows me this error:
No aggregate may appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery that is in a HAVING clause or in a select list, and the column that is aggregated is an outer reference.